# Differences between rendering HTML in PyCharm and a text editor (Sublime Text)

Tags: python, html, css, pycharm

I've got exactly the same files (HTML + CSS), in both PyCharm and Sublime Text, and the results of rendering these in Google Chrome is completely different.

Editing CSS doesn't have any affect on the results of rendering the HTML.

I have to make the project using Python Flas, but I want to start from HTML and CSS.

Does anybody know why have I different results from the same files?

Comment: there are many render engines. ie. Chrome, Firefox and IE/Edge use three different engines. PyCharm can use different than Chrome.

Comment: sonds really weird, are you sure files identical?

Comment: pycharm and sublime text are for editing, I don't see how they could affect the rendering

Comment: but now I noticed that  editing css doesn't any affect on result of rendering html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we run PyCharm project it give us the same link and we have to clear cache or cookies every time we open this link

Answer (score 0):

Let me try a lucky guess since I don't know what is exactly rendering different: it could be the Encoding of the file, you can try and change in Sublime selecting a different enconding type to save the file to match the file saved in pycharm.

File>Save with encoding>[select]

If both are completely equal is the only thing that I can imagine.